Horizontal scroll: sticky element starts moving when scrolling to a certain point
Scenario: There are many rows... each row has a sticky element on the left, a larger content div on the right.
It should be possible to horizontally scroll all rows together and the sticky elements should stay on their initial position.
The issue: When scrolling further than the width of the scrollable container (minus the sticky element width), the sticky elements suddenly start scrolling together with their rows.
When giving the row a fixed width (large content width + sticky element width = 5300px) then it works. But of course, that is not a real solution.
The HTML looks like this:
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row__sticky">Sticky</div>
    <div class="row__content">Large Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row__sticky">Sticky</div>
    <div class="row__content">Large Content</div>
  </div>
</div>

This is the styling:
.container {
  border: 3px solid lightgreen;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.row {
  border: 5px solid red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  // width: 5300px; // dirty fix

  .row__sticky {
    display: inline-block;
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    background: white;
  }

  .row__content {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    background: #ff9900
    width: 5000px;
  }
}

Here a codepen to play with: https://codepen.io/spierala-the-lessful/pen/VwoMjRW
To reproduce the issue, make sure to scroll far enough.

The issue: When scrolling further than the width of the scrollable container (minus the sticky element width), the sticky elements suddenly start scrolling together with their rows. This how sticky works. The element sticks to and inside  its closest positionned parent and also moves with it once the parent srolls out of position. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky

Applying width: fit-content; to the .row elements appears to work.

width: fit-content  on .row indeed seems to work.
I also just saw that display: inline-block would also help.
Making sure that .row does not become smaller than its content seems to be the solution.
